# Will the N- or the C- terminal soluble domain be on the extracellular side?

Tags: cell-biology

Here is a homework question

> A single-pass transmembrane protein is destined to be transported to the plasma membrane. In the wild-type protein, a lysine flanks the transmembrane domain on the N- terminal side, and a glutamic acid flanks on the C-terminal side. Both the N- & C-terminal soluble domains carry sequences that can by glycosylated by oligosaccharyltransferase.
>
> After the protein is transported to the plasma membrane, will the N- or the C- terminal soluble domain be on the extracellular side?

My answer is

> N-terminal with lysine will be towards the extracellular side and C-terminal will be towards the cytoplasm.

Does this seem right to you?

Comment: I made a major edit to your post. Please roll back if you don't like the edit. If you agree with the edit, take advantage of it to learn how to ask a good question on Biology.SE (explicit title, highlight the quotation, clearly specify your question, etc...). You should try to add why you think your answer is right.

Comment: **Hints:** 1. Consider the structures of lysine and glutamate. What's the main difference between the two amino acids? 2. What are the rules governing how proteins are trafficked to the cell membrane? When a protein is synthesized, where is it processed and what does this involve?

Comment: Well I know that lysine has a overall positive charge and glutamate has an overal negative charge. So just considering there charge, does the more positive one (lysine) on one side of the transmembrane protein face the extracellylar space?

Comment: At the moment this is at risk of closure - I think it can stay open, but only if you add an explanation of why you think that is the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Luminal/cytoplasmic orientation of single-pass transmembrane proteins is mostly dictated by positively charged residues residing on the cytoplasmic side (*positive-inside rule*) and negatively charged residues being suppressed on the cytoplasmic side/preferred on the luminal side (*negative inside depletion/outside enrichment rule*).

Since your molecule has a positively charged Lys residue on its N-terminus and a negative negatively charged Glu residue on its C-terminal side your protein would most likely acquire a **type II integral membrane protein topology**, i.e. the C-terminal part would be directed towards the extracellular space while the N-terminal part is in the cytosol.

Further references can be found here:

**Baker JA et al.**, *Charged residues next to transmembrane regions revisited: “Positive-inside rule” is complemented by the “negative inside depletion/outside enrichment rule”* BMC Biol. 2017 [pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28738801)

**Ott CM and Lingappa VR**, *Integral membrane protein biosynthesis: why topology is hard to predict.* J. Cell. Sci. 2002 [pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11973342)

Comment: Hello! This question was deemed worth of an answer, so why not upvote it? [Vote early, vote often](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/vote-early-vote-often?rq=1) to encourage new users and keep the community alive!